# Prompt for Input Inside For Loop

Tags: batch-file, ms-dos, prompt

I have a directory that can contain over a hundred files. I want to create a loop that will go through each file in that directory and ask the user if they want to process the next file or exit the script all together. I can't seem to get the prompt to work inside for the For Loop. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off
Color 1F

SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 

Echo File Processing Screen
Echo.

:UserPrompt1
Set /p "strContProc=Are you sure you wish to process these files? (Y/N) %=%"

If /i "%strContProc%" == "y" (
Goto ProcFiles

) Else If /i "%strContProc%" == "n" (
Goto ProcCancel1

) Else (
Goto UserPrompt1
)

:ProcFiles
If exist "%userprofile%\Desktop\PCExport\Disable" (

Set /a numTotFile = 0
Set /a numFileCount = 0

For /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
Set /a numTotFile += 1
)

) ELSE (
Goto DirNotFound
)

If %numTotFile% EQU 0 (
    Goto NoFilesFound

    ) ELSE If %numTotFile% EQU 1 (
    Echo Processing file !numFileCount! of %numTotFile%...
    Goto EndProc

    ) ELSE (
    Echo.
    Echo %numTotFile% Files will now be processed.
    Echo.
)

:ReturnProc
For /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
Set /a numFileCount += 1
Echo Processing file !numFileCount! of %numTotFile%. . .
Echo.
Echo !numFileCount! >> %%f

If !numFileCount! EQU %numTotFile% (
Echo !numFileCount! of %numTotFile% files have been processed.  
Goto EndProc
)   

:UserPrompt2
Set /p "strNextProc=Do you wish to process the next file? (Y/N)  %=%"

If /i "%strNextProc%" == "y" (
Goto ReturnProc

    ) Else If /i "%strNextProc%" == "n" (
    Goto ProcCancel2

    ) Else (
    Goto UserPrompt2
)

)

Goto EndProc

:DirNotFound
Echo The specified processing directory could not be found!
Goto EndProc

:NoFilesFound
Echo Processing cannot continue. There were no export files found to process.
Goto EndProc

:ProcCancel1
Echo.
Echo Processing of files was canceled at the user's request.
Goto EndProc

:ProcCancel2
Echo.
Echo Processing of files was canceled at the user's request. Please make a note of the last file that was processed.
Goto EndProc

:EndProc
EndLocal
Echo.
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Issuing a `GOTO` within the body of a `FOR` loop immediately terminates the loop.

A simple solution is to write a `:subroutine` outside of the loop that contains the `GOTO`, and call the `:subroutine` from within the loop.

The pseudo code would be something like the following:

```
for ... in (...) do (
   Possibly do some processing
   call :userPrompt
   Possibly do some more processing with !var!
)
exit /b

:userPrompt
set "var="
set /p "var=Your prompt
if ...InvalidInput... goto :userPrompt
exit /b
```

Comment: But `exit /b` will just leave the subroutine, to propagate the decision to leave I'd  `exit /b 1` and attach a conditional execution on fail `||` to the `call :userprompt || exit /b 1`

Comment: @LotPings - For an expected binary input, sure. But my pseudo code is intended to be more generic.

Comment: 0

 
Placing the prompt as a subroutine did what I had hoped but caused the For Loop to reset to the first file; never advancing to the subsequent files. I understand why this occurred since the GOTO immediately terminates the loop. How do I advance to the next file?